# start two SqlDependency on same sqlconnection but different sql commands

Tags: sql, sqlcommand, service-broker, sqldependency

I build some service that on start open two threads, each one start SqlDependency with same sql connection but the **command its different**.

Its possible? its seems to working, but after some will when the on change event need wake up its doesnt.

Thanks.

Comment: Connection sharing between threads should *not* be done - unless it is *explicitly* stated as being safe/valid, and under what conditions. (That is, the burden of proof is on the consumer - you - to find such documentation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can submit any number of SqlCommands to be notified, with same or different SQL text (query), on one more many SqlConnection objects.